# Javascript - can it only return false?

Tags: javascript, search

Javascript - can it only return false?

If I delete -

```
else
{
    alert('Keyword has accepted');
    return true; 
}
```

, whole code wont work.

---

```
function required(look_for) 
{
    var empt = look_for;
  
    if (empt.value.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please input a Keyword"); 
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Keyword has accepted');
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What is your code trying to do? It's not at all clear what your goal is here.

Comment: Without an explicit `return` statement, JavaScript methods [implicitly return `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), which evaluates as [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Answer (score -1):

It's probable that it should be empt.length not empt.value.length

This depends on what you send to the function, I assume you sent a string